# How does a component magically receive `dispatch` as its first argument?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a difficulty understanding the magic argument [`dispatch`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) which suddenly appear out of nowhere as the first argument of a presentation component in the example of [`containers/AddTodo.js`](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#containersaddtodojs).

```
let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
    /* Omitted */
}

AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)
```

So far, my understanding is that the first `AddTodo` is considered a **Presentation component** and the latter is the **Container component**

In this case, a presentation component seems to be injected with `dispatch` as first argument. Unfortunately, I got confused after looking back and realized that is not the case for [the rest of the presentation component](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#componentstodojs).

```
const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => (
    /* Omitted */
)

Todo.propTypes = {
  onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  completed: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}
```

How does the `dispatch` argument appear in a presentation component?

Comment: There are hyperlink error to the example...

Answer (score 6):

When you use `connect()` in: `AddTodo = connect()(AddTodo)` your are injecting `AddTodo` component with a `dispatch` without listening to the store. `dispatch` is now available in your component via props. It can be called `this.props.dispatch()` or directly as `dispatch()` if you use parameter destructuring, i.e. `let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) ...`

Here is a detailed description in the official redux docs: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options

> connect([mapStateToProps], [mapDispatchToProps], [mergeProps], [options])
>
> [mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function): If an object is passed, each function inside it will be assumed to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names, but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props. If a function is passed, it will be given dispatch. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses dispatch to bind action creators in your own way. (Tip: you may use the bindActionCreators() helper from Redux.) **If you omit it, the default implementation just injects dispatch into your component’s props.** If ownProps is specified as a second argument, its value will be the props passed to your component, and mapDispatchToProps will be re-invoked whenever the component receives new props.

Comment: Just to stress about the parameter destructuring. It's not that the first parameter 'magically' is the `dispatch`function. The parameter is actually the `props` passed down to the component with a `dispatch` property attached.

Comment: Thank you for the emphasis on the default behavior... I had miss this line, until your **Bold** format.... :)

Comment: Thank you @DiegoCardosa, I've updated my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Glad to help, @piotr. One thing though, it's "CardosO" ;) lol

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry @DiegoCardoso ;)

Comment: As a side note, this question is answered in the Redux FAQ: http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-props-dispatch

Comment: Yeo, does the above answer your question or would you like me to add anything?

Answer (score 1):

react-redux [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) can receive a `mapDispatchToProps` argument to wrap your action creators with a `dispatch` call. If `mapDispatchToProps` is not passed, `connect` will use the [default `mapDispatchToProps`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connect.js#L11):

```
const defaultMapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ dispatch })
```

As you can see an object with the `dispatch` property is returned. This object will be merged with the props from `mapStateToProps`, and any props passed by attributes to the component (`ownProps`). The end object will be the props passed to the original component by `connect`.

Comment: Oh, i see,... Thanks for the emphasis on the source code. It is more explicit for me to understand how the default was implemented as mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

As Piotr Berebecki, stated `connect()` injects dispatch.  It injects it into props, and `({dispatch})` is destructuring dispatch from props, and assigning it to the variable `dispatch`.

You could rewrite `AddTodo`:

```
let AddTodo = (props) => {
 const { dispatch } = props;
...
};
```